# Android doesn't take values from values-mdpi folder

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support, android-screen, android-resolution

Why Android isn't taking the values from the folder **values-mdpi**
 for the density and size of the screen below?

 PS: There is a **dimens.xml** inside **values-mdpi** folder.

The reference (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says it should take:
Medium density (160), mdpi -> **320x480**

[image: Android values mdpi]

Comment: Details like device, resolution and density will be helpful

Comment: try the folder name as `values-normal for mdpi` and `values-large for hdpi`